# Django: Add my own form to the admin backend?

Tags: python, django-admin

I'm using the Django Admin module. It displays a list of models to edit by app. I would like to add another form to this list. It won't edit a specific model, but it will edit settings that are stored in the database. Is this possible?

Comment: If the settings are stored in the database, could you use a model for them too? Are these global settings or related to apps?

Comment: @squiddy Yes, these are global settings. (Is there a better way to do this with Django?)

Answer (score 1):

You may check out [Django Live Settings](https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-livesettings). It was split out of the [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) project and looks to do what you're looking for.

Otherwise, you may look into [Overriding the Django Admin Templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). You could just override the [index](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.4/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html) template and add your links to the bottom.